# Scenario where we can use abstract class only over interface class in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oop

I have already read about why we use Interface class and why we use Abstract class but still, there is one question which interviewer keeps on asking below 2 scenarios-

- Give me one scenario where I can use only Abstract Class and I can't go with an Interface class?
- Give me one scenario where I can use only Interface Class and I can't go with an Abstract class?

Please don't mark this with duplicate because I searched various place but I didn't get the best answer I am hoping to get clear my confusion?

Comment: Is this a tech test from some company? ;D

Comment: No Matias,Its not a test its is a scenario based interview question which interviewer asks most of the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Give me one scenario where I can use only Abstract Class and I can't
>   go with an Interface <strike>class</strike>?

You want to provide a set of both abstract and concrete behaviors and properties:

```
public class Polygon
{
    // Sides is concrete
    public int Sides { get; set; }

    public abstract double CalculateArea();
    public abstract double CalculatePerimeter();
}
```

> Give me one scenario where I can use only Interface <strike>Class</strike> and I can't go with an Abstract class?

You want to provide a contract that must be fulfilled by some class and the whole class needs to inherit a class already.

Since C# luckily doesn't support *multi-inheritance*, if an `Employee` is a `Person` it won't be able to inherit an abstract class with role-oriented members. Hence, you need to use interfaces:

```
public interface IHasRole
{
     string Role { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person, IHasRole
{
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

Actually you shouldn't choose when to use abstract classes or interfaces based on just the lack of multi-inheritance support. You use interfaces to define API contracts while you use abstract classes to define non-instantiable top-level classes which are concepts that **can't** exist per se. For example: does a *chair* exist? No, but a *woody chair* does!

I suggest that you take a look at some article I published a while ago: [Why and when to use abstract classes](http://designpattern.ninja/news/2016/12/31/why-and-when-to-use-abstract-classes).

Oh, and note how I've crossed out **class** whenever you said ***interface class***. There's no such construct: there're classes and interfaces.

Comment: Thanks Matias your article really helped me to understand where i can go for abstract class

Comment: @RahulSharma I'm glad it've been a good start for you :) Thank you for reading it

Answer (score 1):

I can give you an example of the `Template Method` pattern. We cannot implement `Template Method` pattern by using interface. We have to use abstract classes for that purpose. According to GOF it `Define the skeleton of an algorithm in an operation, deferring some steps to subclasses. Template Method lets subclasses redefine certain steps of an algorithm without changing the algorithm's structure`. So imagine we have an algorithms that consist of some steps and we want to redefine some steps in the future. General code structure of the `Template Method` pattern is like the following. First we define skeleton of algorithm by using abstract class.

```
 public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    protected abstract void Step1();
    protected abstract void Step2();
    protected abstract void Step3();

    // The "Template method". That is the skeleton of our algorithm
    public void TemplateMethod()
    {
        Step1();
        Step2();
        Step3();
    }
}
```

Then we create actual implementation to change that steps.

```
public class ConcreteClassA : AbstractClass
{
    protected override void Step1()
    {
        //redefine Step1
    }

    protected override void Step2()
    {
        //redefine Step2
    }

    protected override void Step3()
    {
        //redefine Step3
    }
}
```

And finally we use that in our client app.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConcreteClassA operation = new ConcreteClassA();
        operation.TemplateMethod();
    }
}
```

By the way `Template Method` patterns are also implemented in the asp.net page life-cycle events behind the scenes. When it comes to interface the advantage of using interface is that the interfaces are more flexible because a class can implement multiple interfaces but can derive only from one base class.